# Is creating a class outside the activity to store variables a good idea in Android?

Tags: android

I used to pass information between Activity by using the Intent.putExtra(String tag, String content) method, but feel like a bit troublesome to do it this way. Then I think may be I can create a class outside of the Activity and store the information I need as static. Then I have consistent way to store and retrieve data in between activity and fragment and keep these variables in one class.

Is this way problematic?

Comment: Process death will clear it out unless you persist to a Bundle.

Comment: It depends on what it. If it is constant, then yes. If it is variable, then no. Unless you can ensure it is always initialized and not changed by your other part of your programming unexpectedly.

Comment: Singletons are often considered an anti-pattern. Depending on the data, perhaps alternatives include Sqlite or SharedPreferences.

Comment: I have seen that some developer keep the tag of putExtra into a class outside of the Activity and access it, so I think that why don't I create a variable outside of the activity to store that information. Now seems like it is not recommended to store variables outside activity and I would stick to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Shared preferences where possible because they are much better at retrieving small amounts of data around the application

Retrieve data

```
    SharedPreferences preferences2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(check.getApplicationContext());
    String simage = preferences2.getString("BytetoSave", "");
```

Set Data

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("BytetoSave",saveThis);
            editor.apply();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use of Application Class:**
Access to variables across the Application,
you can use the Application to start certain things like analytics etc. since the application class is started before Activitys or Servicess are being run. This is not problematic.

Comment: I did not extend the application class. The class I created do not extend any other class.